# Adding legends to stacked bars

Tags: r

I have created the below data frame and want to create a stacked bar chart showing the percentages of available habitats (`main.Avail`) alongside the percentage of used habitats (`main.Used50K`). I have used the `barplot(as.matrix(subset))` function but I can't seem add legends indicating the different habitat categories (`NA`, `BOG`, `F`, `OIP`, `RG`, `RIP`, `UM`) in the stacked bar charts. How can I do this?

```
  main.Hab main.Avail main.Used50K
1     <NA>   4.186001    0.7795595
2      BOG   8.128698    1.4224366
3        F  12.294499    0.4780462
4      OIP  43.902867   69.9860934
5       RG   7.488637    2.3009635
6      RIP   9.713074   22.7798587
7       UM  14.286223    2.2530800
```

Comment: Did you want the barplot as two groups of 7  OR as 7 groups of 2?

Comment: two groups of seven.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by changing the `row.names`

```
m1 <- as.matrix(df1[-1])
row.names(m1) <- df1[,1]
barplot(m1, legend = TRUE)
```

Comment: you solved the problem,  but I suspect that the OP was looking for something more like  
`barplot(m1, beside=TRUE, col=rainbow(7), legend = TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you.  This code: m1 <- as.matrix(df1[-1])
row.names(m1) <- df1[,1]
barplot(m1, legend = TRUE) seems to have worked. However the legend is overlapping with the barplot. Do you know how to separate the legend from the bar plot?

Comment: @M.Thornton  You can use the `args.legend` to change the position.  Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18688847/position-legend-of-a-stacked-bar-plot)